# display multiple dropdown options from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi i have a user table and i want to show their columns as select box on my webpage

below is my code

```
$query = mysql_query("QUERY HERE"); 

echo '<select name="id">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'</option>';
     }
 echo '</select>';

echo '<select name="username">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['username'].'">'.$row['username'].'</option>';
     }
 echo '</select>';

echo '<select name="city">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['usercity'].'">'.$row['usercity'].'</option>';
     }
 echo '</select>';
```

The above code showing ID values in drop-down but username and usercity drop down is showing blank

Comment: check if you are getting values in array by printf(mysql_fetch_array($query))

Comment: may be you are only fetching `id` in query

Answer (score 0):

By your code , a result will be only for the first loop unless you repeat the query above every while loop , So it is better to Try this one :

```
$result = array();

$query = mysql_query("QUERY HERE"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$result[] = $row;

}


echo '<select name="id">';
foreach ($result as $row ){
echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'</option>';
 }
echo '</select>';

echo '<select name="username">';
foreach ($result as $row ){
echo '<option value="'.$row['username'].'">'.$row['username'].'</option>';
 }
echo '</select>';

echo '<select name="city">';
foreach ($result as $row ){
echo '<option value="'.$row['usercity'].'">'.$row['usercity'].'</option>';
  }
echo '</select>';
```